# How to resize and move background shape in Visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio

I created a background for a template, but it seems MS hasn't really worked out this part. The default backgrounds are ugly for one thing. I tried to resize a shape, or move it but haven't found a way to do that. I hover the mouse over the resize points, Visio shows me the "resize object" message in a bubble (or sg, my Office is not english), but I cannot resize it, it's like it's stuck.
Anyone knows how to resize or move it? I also want to put that text to the left of the document but moving is also a mission impossible. However, I can rotate it, hurray...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the shape, select "show shape sheet"
Then, at "shape transform" part, first row show width. Thee's a function like: =GUARD(Sheet.1!Width*0.721). If you change the 0.7xxx value to 1, the shape size will extend to page width. You can change width or height accordingly with same procedure. Sorry this site doesnot allow to post imeges.

hope this helps !

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You don't yet have [privileges to add images](http://superuser.com/privileges/new-user), but you can post a link to the image and add a comment asking it to be embedded into your post. Someone with enough reputation will do it soon.